Dispersive shift of a transmon qubit-cavity system
I am playing with scQubits to explore the coupling between a qubit (transmon) and a cavity. In particular, I would like to simulate the shift in energy in the dispersive regime.
I have started considering a two-level system and a harmonic oscillator and the result is compatible with the expectations as you can see the resonator frequency is shifted by $\pm\chi$ due to the qubit state.

I want to extend this approach to a transmon qubit, but as you can see, the $\chi$-shifted frequencies are below the bare resonator frequency. As I know from the literature (Blais et al, Reed et al, Bishop et al) the resonator dresses its frequency due to the coupling with the qubit. So its dressed frequency should be
$$\omega_r' = \omega_r - \frac{g^2}{\Delta -E_c}\qquad(\hbar = 1)$$
In this scenario, I would expect a shift of the bare frequency to a higher frequency, due to the coupling with the qubit, and a $\chi$-shifted frequency of the dressed frequency. In this case, I get a configuration where the $\chi$-shifted frequencies are below the bare frequency, which is wrong (as far as I know).

This is the code used for the qubit-cavity system
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scqubits import *

omega_q = 7.8693
omega_r = 10.62524
dim_r = 10
delta = omega_q - omega_r
chi = 1.50 * 1e-3
g = np.sqrt(- chi * delta)

qubit = Oscillator(E_osc = omega_q, truncated_dim = 2)
resonator = Oscillator(E_osc = omega_r, truncated_dim = dim_r)

hilbertspace = HilbertSpace([qubit, resonator])
hilbertspace.add_interaction(g = g, op1 = qubit.creation_operator, op2 = resonator.annihilation_operator, add_hc = True)
hilbertspace.generate_lookup()

transitions = []
max_jumps = range(1, dim_r - 1)
max_dim_r = range(1, dim_r)

for jump in range(1, max_jumps[-1] + 1):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(jump, dim_r - 1):
            first_state= (i, j - jump)
            second_state  = (i, j)
            
            transition = float((hilbertspace.eigenvals(dim)[hilbertspace.dressed_index(second_state)] - hilbertspace.eigenvals(dim)[hilbertspace.dressed_index(first_state)])/jump)
            transitions.append((first_state, second_state, jump, transition))

df = pd.DataFrame(transitions, columns=["First State", "Final State", "Number of Photons", "Transition Energy"])
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Transition Energy", ascending=False)
df_sorted

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, transition in enumerate(transitions):
    if i == 0:
        ax.vlines(transition[-1], 0, 1, label="Qubit state-dependent frequency")
    else:
        ax.vlines(transition[-1], 0, 1)

ax.vlines(resonator.E_osc, 0, 1, color="tab:orange", label="Bare frequency")

plt.xlim(10.62, 10.63)
plt.title("Dispersive shift")
plt.xlabel("Frequency [GHz]")
plt.ylim(0, 1.25)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('dispersive_shift_qubit.png')
plt.show()

and this one for the transmon-cavity system
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scqubits import *

omega_q = 7.8693
omega_r = 10.62524
alpha = - 0.344
EC = - alpha
EJ = (omega_q + EC)**2/(EC)
dim_r = 10
delta = omega_q - omega_r
chi = 1.50 * 1e-3
g = np.sqrt(- chi * delta * (1 + delta/alpha))

qubit = Transmon(EJ=EJ, EC=EC, ng=0, ncut=40, truncated_dim=dim_r)
resonator = Oscillator(E_osc = omega_r, truncated_dim = dim_r)

hilbertspace = HilbertSpace([qubit, resonator])
hilbertspace.add_interaction(g = g, op1 = qubit.n_operator, op2 = resonator.annihilation_operator, add_hc = True)
hilbertspace.generate_lookup()

dim = hilbertspace.dimension

transitions = []
max_jumps = range(1, dim_r - 1)
max_dim_r = range(1, dim_r)

for jump in range(1, max_jumps[0] + 1):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(jump, max_dim_r[2] - 1):
            first_state= (i, j - jump)
            second_state  = (i, j)
            
            transition = float((hilbertspace.eigenvals(dim)[hilbertspace.dressed_index(second_state)] - hilbertspace.eigenvals(dim)[hilbertspace.dressed_index(first_state)])/jump)
            transitions.append((first_state, second_state, jump, transition))

df = pd.DataFrame(transitions, columns=["First State", "Second State", "Number of Photons", "Transition Energy"])
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Transition Energy", ascending=False)
df_sorted

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, transition in enumerate(transitions):
    if i == 0:
        ax.vlines(transition[-1], 0, 1, label="Qubit state-dependent frequency")
    else:
        ax.vlines(transition[-1], 0, 1)
ax.vlines(resonator.E_osc, 0, 1, color="tab:orange", label="Bare frequency")

plt.title("Dispersive shift")
plt.xlabel("Frequency [GHz]")
plt.ylim(0, 1.25)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('dispersive_shift_transmon.png')
plt.show()

